# s3 delete key with boto3.client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

This would delete all objects in a s3 bucket

```
s3_b=boto3.client("s3")
objects=s3_b.list_objects(Bucket="bucket_name")["Contents"]
for obj in objects:
    s3_b.delete_object(Bucket='bucket_name',Key=obj["Key"])
```

Is there a similar way to delete an object with a particular key path like `s3://bucket_name/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4`, where I want to delete all the objects within folder4

Edit:
Would it be possible to delete objects in two different paths within the same loop
Eg:  `'folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4'` and `'folder1/folder2/folder3/folder5'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/collections.html). For example:

```
import boto3

s3r = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3r.Bucket('bucket_name')

for object in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4'):
    print(object)
    #object.delete() # uncomment to delete
```

Comment: Thank you @Marcin, how does `boto3.resource('s3')` differ from `boto3.client("s3")` and I am performing few other operations after deletion using `boto3.client("s3")` would there be an impact of using both resource and client in the same function

Comment: @pc_pyr `boto3.resource` is more pythonic, higher level interface to aws. `boto3.client` is lower-level interface to aws api. You can use both `resource` and `client` in one program. I'm not aware of any issues where the use of both of them would lead to problems.

Comment: Is there a way we could specify two paths with this method (in the same loop iteration), for eg. `Prefix='folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4'` and `Prefix='folder1/folder2/folder3/folder5'` , thanks@Marcin, also added this example in post for better formatting

Comment: @pc_pyr You would have to run the filter command twice. I don't think you can provide multiple prefixes into one filter.

Comment: `bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4').delete()` also seems to work without for loop, it would be helpful to know the difference between the two: using without loop and iterating in loop thank you @Marcin

Comment: @pc_pyr it's more pythonic than and probably more efficient. But the for loop gives you more possibilities, like you can print out objects first, log them. I don't know internal implementation of filter method to say much more. Anyway if you find my answer helpful, it's acceptance would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to check if the particular key path exists and if yes, then delete @Marcin, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.delete_objects` and pass the objects list as parameter:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_objects